# Is it possible to download the XAP Silverlight web resource from a CRM 2011 organization?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Is it possible to download the XAP Silverlight web resource from a CRM 2011 organization? It looks to me like its compressed or encrypted in the Content column of the dbo.WebResourceBase table. My goal is to download the XAP so that I can compare it to the output of the VS project to see if I am working with the right version of the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To download XAP, you don't need to go to database.

Open CRM 2011 in IE and Go to the Setting > Customization > Customize the System > Web Resources

Open the Silver light web resource you want to download.

Copy the URL (Highlighted in screenshot) and paste in browser, it will give an option to download & Save the XAP file.

[image]